# How do i pass a QR value from javascript to my python view function in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, qr-code

I have created a QR scanner using html and javascript using instascan.min.js as shown in the code below. Currently, I am able to scan and see the content of the QR code displayed on the website but I am not sure how I can POST the QR code output `{scan.content}` . The QR value is passed into `{scan.content}` in the html.

I want to post it to the python function: doctor_qrscan in view_doctor.py so that it can be written into the database Any help is greatly appreciated! The following are the relevant codes:

```
{% block mainbody %}

{% verbatim %}

<div id="app2" class="container">
  <head>
    <title>Instascan &ndash; Demo</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css">-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webrtc-adapter/3.3.3/adapter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <section class="cameras">
          <h2>Cameras</h2>
          <ul>
            <li v-if="cameras.length === 0" class="empty">No cameras found</li>
            <li v-for="camera in cameras">
              <span v-if="camera.id == activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)" class="active">{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</span>
              <span v-if="camera.id != activeCameraId" :title="formatName(camera.name)">
                <a @click.stop="selectCamera(camera)">{{ formatName(camera.name) }}</a>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="scans">
          <h2>Scans</h2>
          <ul v-if="scans.length === 0">
            <li class="empty">No scans yet</li>
          </ul>
          <transition-group name="scans" tag="ul">
            <li v-for="scan in scans" :key="scan.date" :title="scan.content">{{ scan.content }}</li>
          </transition-group>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class="preview-container">
        <video id="preview"></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</div>
{% endverbatim %}

 
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    scanner: null,
    activeCameraId: null,
    cameras: [],
    scans: []
  },

  mounted: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5});
    self.scanner.addListener('scan', function (content, image) {
      self.scans.unshift({ date: +(Date.now()), content: content });
    });

    Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
      self.cameras = cameras;
      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        self.activeCameraId = cameras[0].id;
        self.scanner.start(cameras[0]);
      } else {
        console.error('There is no camera.');
      }
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.error(e);
    });
  },

  methods: {
    formatName: function (name) {
      return name || '(unknown)';
    },
    selectCamera: function (camera) {
      this.activeCameraId = camera.id;
      this.scanner.start(camera);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**<view_doctor.py>**

```
@api_view(['GET',"POST"])
def doctor_qrscan(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # parse the JSON data
    data = json.load(request)
    result = data.get("scan.content")   # Not sure if I am doing it correctly
    
    if result != None:
      c = connection.cursor()
      # Saving the result to database
      c.execute("INSERT INTO doctor_QR (output) VALUES ('{0}');".format(result))
      return Action.success()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using Django REST Framework, I suggest to take advantages of it's features.

That includes using ORM by defining your models instead of using raw SQL statements.
Then you can also use serializers to verify the data and store it in the DB.
I suggest that you start with this tutorial https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Anyway, if you insist in doing it 'manual' way, then `request.data` returns the parsed content of the request body (JSON).

I do not really see how you send the data from the frontend, so I do not know the exact structure of the data sent.